# Are /tl/ and /dl/ rare onsets worldwide?

Tags: cross-linguistic, phonotactics, consonant-clusters

Onsets of stop+liquid are very common, but it seems like /tl/ and /dl/ are much rarer than other stop+liquid onsets, like /gl/ or /pr/.

Are /tl/ and /dl/ especially rare compared to other stop+liquid onsets?

(I wouldn't be surprised at all to find out that they're as common as any others, but just not in the set of languages I'm more familiar with.)

Comment: I'm pretty sure they exist in Nahuatl languages, as in the second syllable of atlatl. I think Classical Nahuatl even has a productive suffix /tli/.

Comment: Also, are there languages where /tl/ is allowed in the coda, but not in the onset?

Comment: @abarnert, /tl/ onsets definitely exist, I'm just trying to find out if they're actually rarer cross-linguistically.

Comment: There some phoneme inventory databases online, and there is the World phonotactics database (on a more abstract level), but I am not aware of consonant cluster inventories suitable to answer this question.

Comment: Maybe it's worth noting in passing that Italian regained /Cl/ onsets through later well-integrated Greek and Latin loanwords: "pianeta", but "planetario"; "chiave", but "clavicola"; and yes, there is "atleta", "atlante".
They are relatively marginal in the phonology, but substantive enough they probably can't be just considered odd outliers.

Comment: @sumelic Yeah, the fact that, e.g., /bl/ but not /tl/ happens to be true in English, Spanish, and Russian (three of the most widespread, and most borrowed-from, languages in the world) could easily lead to a false impression that /bl/ is more common than /tl/ even if it really isn't. So it's important to be careful here.

Comment: @abarnert What is conventionally written <tl> in Classical Nahuatl is not a actually cluster (i.e. /tl/) but is an (voiceless alveolar lateral) affricate (i.e /tɬ/).

Comment: @Miztli Yeah, sumelic's answer covers that nicely, in the first of the bulleted list of "long comments". (That still leaves the question of how, e.g., Mexican Spanish speakers who don't know Nahuatl pronounce borrowed words, but I don't think that's necessarily relevant to the question.)

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't seem to be obvious that /tl/ and /dl/ are especially rare compared to other kinds of stop + liquid onset clusters, so I would be wary of phonological theories or hypotheses that assume or require this to be a fact.

The best discussion that I have found so far is in "[KL > TL sound change in Germanic and elsewhere:
Descriptions, explanations, and implications](http://gc.cuny.edu/CUNY_GC/media/CUNY-Graduate-Center/Images/Programs/Linguistics/Juliette%20Blevins/KL-TLchangeslity-13-2-267.pdf)", by Juliette Blevins and Sven Grawunder (2009), which suggests that even though the absence of /tl/ and /dl/ onsets in English (and also in various other IE languages) seems to be a systemic and not just accidental gap, there doesn't seem to be a universal preference against these clusters:

> Universal constraints of the form *TL have [...] been proposed, in order to express the crosslinguistically marked status of these clusters and to instantiate
>   the fact that “homorganic clusters of this kind are avoided in many languages”
>   (Gouskova 2004: 220). Despite the many analyses of TL gaps, and explanations for their marked status, we are unaware of any typological quantitative
>   study demonstrating that initial TL clusters are underrepresented in the world’s
>   languages. In Section 4.2 we offer preliminary typological findings within and
>   across language families which suggests that they are not.

(§4.1., p. 287 (the page breaks in the linked doc are preliminary, so I don't know whether the published version is slightly different.)

The reference to clusters "of this kind" might be alluding to things like the gaps in English of onset /pw/, /bw/ (not strongly enforced: it could possibly be considered completely accidental, since borrowings like "pueblo" or "bwana" are typically pronounced with /pw/ and /bw/) and /tʃj/, /dʒj/, which can also be seen as being motivated by avoidance of clusters that are in some way overly homorganic.

Some long comments:

- "Tl" and "dl" onsets may be analyzed as unitary phonemes rather than clusters. (Actually, I think I remember seing mono-phonemic analyses for even "pl"-type onsets in some language, but I forget which.) This is the usual analysis for Classical Nahuatl: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nahuatl#Phonology) transcribes its "tl" sound as a phoneme /t͡ɬ/. As abarnert's comment and the name of language indicate, this sound can occur word-finally. Wikipedia indicates that Classical Nahuatl is not analyzed as having any complex onsets.
- In Indo-European languages, the main context where I am familiar with /tl/ and /dl/ being gaps in the inventory of stop + liquid onsets, there seems to also be a weaker dispreference for clusters like /pl bl kl gl fl/ when compared to /pr br kr gr fr/. Or at least, I have the impression that /pl bl kl gl fl/ are less stable than the obstruent + /r/ clusters. For example, Portuguese historically changed l to r in onset clusters in certain words like *branco* < Latin *blancus,* although this is no longer an active change and modern Portuguese does have obstruent + l clusters. [Spanish](https://www.staff.ncl.ac.uk/i.e.mackenzie/cons.htm) changed /pl kl fl/ to /ʎ/ word-initially and to /tʃ/ after consonants, although again we do see these clusters in modern Spanish as a result of borrowing or dialect mixing. Even though "r" and "l" are both liquids/approximants, I know that in some IE languages such as English, /l/ has been analyzed as being less "sonorous" (in terms of the "sonority hierarchy") than /r/ (the evidence in English for this is stuff like the existence of word-final /rl/, e.g. *snarl,* but not word-final /lr/).
- There are IE languages that have /tl/, or /tl/ and /dl/.  Blevins and Grawunder mention Russian, Polish, Serbo-Croatian, Irish, and Pashto (§4.2., (3)), and have more detailed discussion of the different ways languages can get words with these clusters.
- Somewhat differently, [tl, dl] are known to be relatively confusable with [kl, gl] for speakers of many IE languages, and apparently there has been a shift of /kl, gl/ to [tl, dl] (unclear to me whether phonemic or just phonetic) in various languages, including dialects of English! (discussed in Blevins and Grawunder)
- Although I, like jknappen, am unaware of any consonant cluster inventory databases, I found a paper that mentions various examples of languages with complex syllable structure and that summarizes the types of clusters: "[Highly complex syllable structure: a typological study of its phonological characteristics and diachronic
  development](https://digitalrepository.unm.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?referer=https://www.google.com/&httpsredir=1&article=1052&context=ling_etds)," by Shelece Easterday (2017).

  A brief search for "complex onset" in this document turned up mentions of the following languages that are described as having complex onsets where the second consonant may be /l/:

  - [gym] NGÄBERE Chibchan, Guaymiic (Panama)
  - [mji] KIM MUN (VIETNAM DIALECT) Hmong-Mien, Hmong-Mien (Vietnam)
  - [pac] PACOH Austro-Asiatic, Katuic (Vietnam)

  You could check to see whether these or any other of the listed languages have /tl/ or /dl/ clusters.

Comment: Without being reminded of some examples, I'm not sure that Russian or Serbo-Croatian /tl/ is different than that in English words like *motley* or *Atlanta*.

Comment: @AdamBittlingmayer: I think that the languages listed by Blevins and Grawunder are specifically supposed to differ from English in having word-initial /tl/ clusters.

Comment: @AdamBittlingmayer some slavic examples: Polish *tlen* 'oxygen'; Russian *тля* 'aphid'

Comment: Thanks, good examples.  Also *dla*, *для* and *длинный* for /dl/.

Comment: @AdamBittlingmayer One possibly interesting point on _Atlanta_: Some Chicano and Mexican Spanish natives pronounce it with a clear /tl/ in the second syllable, in Spanish and sometimes even in English. From one anecdotal experience (so take this with a huge grain of salt), a Castilian native found it almost incomprehensible and hard to reproduce—he had a hard time hearing it as containing anything _t_-like. General American speakers found it "foreign-sounding" but still easily recognizable and reproducible (less distracting than the different vowel in the first syllable, even).

Comment: One of the languages that uses /t͡ɬ/ as a unitary phoneme is Klingon